# different between SAML reqest, response and token

Tags: saml-2.0

I am trying to test SAML based scenarios, so Anyone can give me idea, different between SAML request, response and SAML token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For authentication in SAML, the Service Provider (the application / SP) sends a SAML AuthnRequest to the Identity Provider (the IDP).

The IDP then presents a login screen to the user.

If the user authenticates, the IDP sends an AuthnResponse to the SP.

This response contains a SAML token. This is in XML and contains the SAML assertions (the claims) about the user e.g. the user's first name is Bob.

There are some examples [here](https://auth0.com/blog/how-saml-authentication-works/).